# Where does Xcode store .m files of a framework?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In Xcode there are many frameworks (like mkmapkit.framework).

This framework contains only .h (header) files. Where can I find the corresponding .m (implementation) files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to see the implementation is to decompile the frameworks static library with tools like those described in this question:

[Decompiling Objective-C libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334072/decompiling-objective-c-libraries)

Since the frameworks you are probably interested in will generally have symbols stripped, it will be a bit of a task understanding what is going on but you can glean some things from tools like these.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation files are not distributed with Xcode. Apple keeps them proprietary.

Answer (score 3):

The framework classes are available as binary library files (.dylib, .a etc. for example). So .m which are implementation source files are not available. Header .h must be available as without header files compiling is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can find them inside Apple's internal source code repositories.  If you work at Apple on an appropriate team, you can check them out.  If you don't, then you're out of luck.