# Where to find .m files of iOS framework

Tags: iphone, ios5

I m going through framework files that comes with iOS, like Twitter.framework. What i can see is that it all contains the .h files, where as i want to see the implementation files, is there any way to view them?

Comment: you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4728125/845115

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, and in the vast majority of cases you should have no need to beyond your own curiosity.

The .h files are provided so that your code can link to the Apple provided API's. You don't have a technical need to see the implementation and Apple doesn't provide them presumably because they don't want you to see their implementation. There are valid reasons for this such as protecting their intellectual property and maintaining a certain level of security by obscurity within the OS components.

Comment: this always bothered me.  i don't like having to rely on their documentation to understand how the frameworks operate.  they can't include every little detail about the code.  it would be much easier if we could see it.  on the other, their reasons for keeping the .m's secret are understandable.  still a shame though.

Answer (score 3):

No, Apple does not supply any implementation files for their frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

we cant see the m file of any frameworks.
all we can get is only .h files.

Answer (score 2):

if the implementation's source files are not provided and a binary is provided for you to link to, then that is by intent. some libraries provide their implementations, and some do not.