# Objective C decompiler

Tags: objective-c, decompiling, disassembly, decompiler

What's the best way to decompile Objective-C applications and libraries? I know about Apple's own `otool` but was wondering if there is a more user friendly app with some code beatification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompiling Objective-C libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334072/decompiling-objective-c-libraries)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this question might introduce a lot of different opinions, [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) is pretty GUI.

Comment: Never decompiled Objective-c before; just wanted something to check for the API URL an old IPA was connecting to; used hopper and figured it out in about a minute.  Very handy - even the free version.