# Reverse engineering objective-c interfaces from static library (like class-dump-z)

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries, reverse-engineering

I have a static library written in objective-c. I have it in the form of a libFoo.a file.

I'd like to extract the classes and methods that are contained within the library, similar to the output of class-dump-z.

I've tried using `otool -tV` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334072/decompiling-objective-c-libraries).

However, the output is very verbose and includes lots of things other than just the interface declarations.

Per comment from H2CO3, I tried RuntimeBrowser, which seems like an excellent tool. However, opening the .a files from File -> Open didn't seem to do anything. Could be because I was using the Mac version and trying to inspect an iOS library.

I've also tried running class-dump-z against the static library but it doesn't appear to work:

```
/**
 * This header is generated by class-dump-z 0.2a.
 * class-dump-z is Copyright (C) 2009 by KennyTM~, licensed under GPLv3.
 *
 * Source: (null)
 */
```

Tried regular class-dump but got this error message:

> Error: Fat file doesn't contain a valid Mach-O file for the specified
>   architecture (i386).  It probably means that class-dump was run on a
>   static library, which is not supported.

I downloaded the evaluation version of IDA for Mac (6.4.1303322) and so far it's been the best yet. Very useful--just pop open the static library and you can see a list of the classes and it understands Objective-C 2.0 syntax and you can see the methods.

That being said, I'd still love to see a way to get the output in the same format as class-dump-z.

Anyone know of a way to extract the classes and methods that are contained in an objective-c static library? I can see them in the stack when I stop in the debugger and when I use `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` so I know the debugging symbols are present.

Comment: How are debugging symbols relevant? BTW if class-dump should work. Or class-dump-x or class-dump-z (just google'em). If everything fails, try RuntimeBrowser (google that as well).